# 4 green balls and 7 blue balls

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many combinations for those 11 balls

A. All combinations

B. which no green balls adjoining

A. There are 11 positions
What i know, after we put 1 balls in one positions the next time we have one less ball for the next positions 
But i can't understand how to apply combinations formula for this

B. _G_G_G_G_
There 5 positions for 7 blue balls to be put
And 3 middle positions must filled with blue balls, so there are 4 blue balls left for 5 positions.

But, how is it exactly? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (A), we have $11$ available positions from which we simultaneously select a subset of $4$ of those positions to be used by the green balls.

We have $11$ positions and we **choose** $4$ of them.  $11$ choose $4$.  The answer will be $\binom{11}{4}$ (*read aloud as $11$ choose $4$*).  Remember that there are precisely $\binom{n}{r}$ ways to choose a subset of $r$ objects from a set of $n$ objects.

For (B), rather than placing the green balls first and fitting the blue inbetween... you would be better off by placing the blue balls first and making space to each side and placing the green balls in those spaces, using at most one green ball per space.

So, we have our $7$ blue balls arranged with spaces like so:

$$\underline{~~~}B\underline{~~~}B\underline{~~~}B\underline{~~~}B\underline{~~~}B\underline{~~~}B\underline{~~~}B\underline{~~~}$$

There are $8$ spaces available from which we want to *choose* $4$ of them to be used by the green balls.

> As an aside, you could have continued in the fashion that you started, having placed the green balls first and inserting a blue ball into each important gap., leaving you with four blue balls left to place into the five available gaps but allowing more than one ball per gap.  We could continue with [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to get $\binom{4+5-1}{5-1}$ ways to continue, which of course equals the answer we would have gotten in the other way of $\binom{8}{4}$.  Stars-and-bars requires a bit more prerequisite knowledge however, so I would expect that you should have understood the first approach, but not necessarily the stars-and-bars approach.